# WooCommerce: Set Permalink for attributes filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url-rewriting, permalinks

I want to set new permalink structure as below.

Current URL : http://localhost/tech/?product_cat=3-sits-soffa&filter_form=svangd

New URL: http://localhost/tech/3-sits-soffa/svangd

I have also tried with add_rewrite_tag and add_permastruct but not working for me.

Here is the code which I have used.

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite1' );
   function custom_rewrite1() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '(.?.+?)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&filter_form=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
```